# customized calendar app for iOS

Tags: ios, calendar

I am a complete beginner to iOS development.I want to work with calendar. My jobs is to download some data(like birthday,reminder) from remote server and mention it in a calendar. Again upload some event(like birthday or reminder) entered into calendar to server. Is there any tutorial for these work.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following tutorials for iOS Calender:

1. http://oleb.net/blog/2012/05/creating-and-deleting-calendars-in-ios/
2. http://maniacdev.com/2011/09/open-source-customizable-ios-calendar-component-with-landscape-orientation-support

These may help you.

Answer (score 3):

Apple provides following resources which might be helpful to you

Calendar and Reminders Programming Guide

[Calendar and Reminders](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004759-SW1)

demo source code for Event kit which can be found at

[SimpleEKDemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010160)